# ¿Como validar un TextField despues de perder el foco?

Tags: validación, flutter

Actualmente realizo la validación mediante onChange, pero mi intención es que cuando el usuario pase a otro campo de texto el `TextField` cuando pierda el **foco** se valide y muestre un mensaje de error en caso de haberlo.

```
new TextField(
          controller: textController,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Email',
        border: InputBorder.none ,
        labelText: 'Ingrese su Email',
        errorText: _validate ? "Dato no valido" : null
      ),
      keyboardType:TextInputType.emailAddress,
      onChanged: (validate){
       setState(() {
        if (validanco(validate)) {
          _validate = false;
        }else _validate = true;
        });
      },
      onEditingComplete: () =>FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusnobe),
    ),
```

El método `validanco()` regresa una balor de tipo `bool` el cual si esta bien el texto regresa `true`.

Busque la documentación de `FocusNode` pero no encontre algun metodo que me ayude a validar cuando el usuario cambia de `TtextField`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es crear un `FocusNode` , asignarlo a tu `TextField` y agregar un listener al `FocusNode` para escuchar los cambios de foco.

```
  //Declarando el focusNode
  FocusNode _focusEmail =FocusNode();


  @override
  void initState() {
    //escuchando cambios de foco
    _focusEmail.addListener(() {

      if (_focusEmail.hasFocus){
        print("tiene el foco");
      } else {
        print("perdió el foco");
      }

    },);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Asignandole el foco:

```
TextField(
         focusNode: _focusEmail,
          controller: textController,
          ...
```